Handling Accented Characters in Glossary Entries without Escape Sequences
With this minimal example demonstrating a glossary entry with an accented name (É), the glossary generates the following incorrect group heading in the .gls file: \glsgroupheading{�}.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{gls:element}{
    name={Élément},
    description={Some description}
}

\begin{document}
Here is a reference to \gls{gls:element}.
\printglossaries
\end{document}

I'm compiling with latexmk -lualatex.
Interestingly, if I escape the diacritical marks using name={\'{E}l\'{e}ment}, the issue is resolved. However, since I'm working with a UTF-8 document, I'd prefer not to rely on pre-Unicode escape sequences. Also the issue isn't exactly with the name entry, but the \glsgroupheading generated.
Is there an alternative solution to handle accented characters directly in the glossary without using escape sequences?
Here my .latexmkrc:
$pdf_mode = 4;
$bibtex_use = 1;
$log_file_mode = 1;
$failure_cmd = 'echo "Error during the compilation of file: %S"';

set_tex_cmds( '--shell-escape -file-line-error %O %S' );


add_cus_dep('glo', 'gls', 0, 'run_makeglossaries');
add_cus_dep('acn', 'acr', 0, 'run_makeglossaries');

sub run_makeglossaries {
    my ($base_name, $path) = fileparse( $_[0] );
    pushd $path;
    if ( $silent ) {
        system "makeglossaries -q '$base_name'";
    }
    else {
        system "makeglossaries '$base_name'";
    };
    popd;
}

push @generated_exts, 'glo', 'gls', 'glg';
push @generated_exts, 'acn', 'acr', 'alg';

$clean_ext .= ' %R.ist %R.xdy %R.maf %R.mtc*';


you may be working with utf-8 but you are sorting it using makeindex which predates utf-8 by a few decades....

@DavidCarlisle That's interesting, is there a millennium alternative? Thinking of xindy ?

probably (or you could do something in Lua) but I'm not sure if any are hooked up to work with the glossaries package by default. Someone will probably answer though.

Xindy seems to work.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[xindy]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{gls:element}{
    name={Élément},
    description={Some description}
}

\begin{document}
Here is a reference to \gls{gls:element}.
\printglossaries
\end{document}


If you want groups, use style=indexgroup.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[xindy,style=indexgroup]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{gls:element}{
    name={Élément},
    description={Some description}
}

\begin{document}
Here is a reference to \gls{gls:element}.
\printglossaries
\end{document}



Wonderful, I may need the changes to my .latexmkrc (just updated the question). I currently don't call makeindex, but makglossaries. I think I need to call xindy somewhere

@nowox I used lualatex-makeglossaries-lualatex.
